# ASPxPopupControl clear all layout group

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to clear all contents in all LayoutGroups.

So I use

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="AspxPopUPDeneme" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="AspxPopUPDeneme" ClientSideEvents-Closing="function(s,e){ASPxClientEdit.ClearEditorsInContainerById('form_clear');}">
        <ContentCollection>
            <dx:PopupControlContentControl>

            <div id="form_clear">
                 <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayoutDeneme" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ASPxFormLayoutDeneme">
                    <Items>
                        <dx:TabbedLayoutGroup>
                            <Items>
                               <dx:LayoutGroup>....</dx:LayoutGroup>
                               <dx:LayoutGroup>....</dx:LayoutGroup>
                            </Items>
                        </dx:TabbedLayoutGroup>                             
                    </Items>
                </dx:ASPxFormLayout>
            </div>
```

But this method only clear active LayoutGroup when I closing the PopUp. 
[My problem as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIldv.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `ClearEditorsInContainerById` clears all visible editors (i.e. in active tab) that belongs to a container group given by certain `containerId`. To include invisible editors on other tab, use 3-argument version of `ClearEditorsInContainerById` as shown below:

```
function clearAllOnClose(s, e)
{
    ASPxClientEdit.ClearEditorsInContainerById('form_clear', null, true);
}

<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="AspxPopUPDeneme" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="AspxPopUPDeneme" 
ClientSideEvents-Closing="clearAllOnClose">
    <ContentCollection>
    <dx:PopupControlContentControl runat="server">
          <div id="form_clear">
              <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayoutDeneme" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ASPxFormLayoutDeneme">
              <Items>
                  <dx:TabbedLayoutGroup>
                  <Items>
                      <dx:LayoutGroup>....</dx:LayoutGroup>
                      <dx:LayoutGroup>....</dx:LayoutGroup>
                  </Items>
                  </dx:TabbedLayoutGroup>                             
              </Items>
              </dx:ASPxFormLayout>
          </div>
    </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

Setting `true` in third argument means that null values are assigned to all controls under `form_clear` div container, regardless of their visibility status.

Note from documentation:

> If the validationGroup parameter is set to null, the method clears
>   all/visible (under the clearInvisibleEditors parameter value) editors
>   located within the specified container.

Reference:

[DevExpress Documentation: ClearEditorsInContainerById](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientEdit_ClearEditorsInContainerByIdtopic(kIfsog))